# maximal possible variance of a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

What is the maximal possible variance of a random variable that takes values in the set
$[−1, 1]$?

Let's say $X$ is our random variable. I assumed maximum variance occurs when $X$ is uniformly distributed over this interval.

Thus as we know $\text{Var}(X) = \frac{(b - a)^2}{12}$  which evaluates in this case to $\frac{1}{3}.
$

Is this the right way to go about it or am I missing the point of the question? Cause it felt like it's too easy to be true.

Comment: Consider $X$ such that $\Pr(X = 1) = \Pr(X = -1) = 1/2$. What is the variance of $X$?

Comment: Your assumption has not been justified and turns out to be wrong.

Comment: Thank you now I can see the reason why it is wrong. Appreciate that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any random variable supported in the interval $[-1, 1]$ we have $X^2 \leq 1$ and $E[X]^2 \geq 0$ so
$$\text{Var}(X) = E[X^2] - E[X]^2 \leq 1$$

By taking $X$ to be the symmetric Bernoulli random variable ($P(X=1)=P(X=-1)=1/2$) it's easy to see that this bound is achieved and so the maximum variance of a random variable that takes its values in $[-1,1]$ is $1$.